# Controlling the execution of a method via Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to have two classes, one class has two methods each of which will take a while to execute completely. The second class is given information which will decide which one of the two methods in the first class will execute. It is important however that if the second class (which will be executing at the same time in its own thread) decides that the other of the two methods should execute, the first class would go straight to executing the other method and not have to wait for the first to finish.

If class A has the two methods and class B is in parallel in a different thread deciding which method to execute then here is an example:
A is executing method 1 which will take a while to return. During the execution of method 1, class B decides method 2 should execute which means class A should immediately stop doing method 1 and go on to execute method 2.

Is this possible? Maybe with interrupts?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an outline of something that should work:

```
class ClassA implements Runnable {

    public volatile boolean switchToOther;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        switchToOther = false;
        try {
            method1();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Restore the interrupted status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        if (switchToOther) {
            method2();
        }
    }

    public void method1() throws InterruptedException {
        work();
    }

    public void method2() throws InterruptedException {
        otherWork();
    }
}

class ClassB implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        Thread t = new Thread(a);
        t.start();
        if (decideToSwitch()) {
            a.switchToOther = true;
            t.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

1. `InterruptedException` can happen beyond your control, so you should check it's due to an explicit switch,
2. the `volatile` on the `switchToOther` field used from several threads,
3. the resetting of the interrupted state, which is standard idiom when catching `InterruptedException`

Answer (score 4):

If you make Class A implement runnable and then execute its method by having Class B create a new Thread with an object of type Class A, you can have Class B call the interrupt method on the Class A thread.